# How do I make a decorated service injectable?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a decorator factory function:

```
 export function CustomDecorator (dummyProp: string) {
    
    return function<T extends {new (...args: any[]): any}> (ctor: T) {
        @Injectable()
        class MyCustomClass extends ctor {
            myProp = dummyProp;
            constructor(..._: any[]) {
                super(_);
            }
        }
        return MyCustomClass;
    }
}
```

I then have a service that I want to be injectable as well as being decorated with the above function:

```
@Injectable()
@CustomDecorator('helloWorld')
export class MyService {
   /* ... */
}
```

However, this doesn't work and I get the following error:
No provider for MyCustomClass!

How do I make this work?

Comment: If not already done, you probably need to provide the MyCustomClass (although its an service) in the provide array of the MyService module

Comment: You can't do that since MyCustomClass is created at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working by simply specifying the use of a service factory:

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
  {provide: MyService, useFactory: () => new MyService()}
]
})
```